# Given Y Bin ~ (10,0.4) and Z Geo ~ (0.3) find P(Y+Z=2)

Tags: probability

Given Y Bin ~ (10,0.4) and Z Geo ~ (0.3) find P(Y+Z=2)

Why is the solution to this P(Y=0)P(Z=2)+P(Y=1)P(Z=1)?

Why doesn't P(Y=2)P(Z=0) need to be included in this solution?

Comment: You missed saying $Y$ and $Z$ are independently distributed.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on how one parametrizes the geometric distribution.  There is, for example, the parametrization

$$\Pr[Z = z] = p(1-p)^z, \quad z = 0, 1, 2, \ldots,$$

which counts the number of **failures** before the first success, and

$$\Pr[Z = z] = p(1-p)^{z-1}, \quad z = 1, 2, 3, \ldots,$$

which counts the number of **trials** to observe the first success.  Depending on which parametrization is intended, the answer to the question varies.

Comment: We are using Pr[Z=z]=p(1−p)z−1,z=1,2,3,…,

Answer (score 0):

For both the Bin dist and the Geo dist, we have that the values of $x$ must be $\geq 0$.

This is why you must consider all the cases.

If we have $P(Y+Z=2)$, then you must consider the following cases:

$(Y,Z)=(0,2),(1,1),(2,0)$

**However**, the Geo dist is concerned with the number of failures before the first success. Consider a coin being tossed 5 times with success being the event of a head. It does not make sense to find the probability of the number of tails being $0$. This is why we tend to ignore the case where $Y=0$.

In any case, if you can justify, you should get the points. It really comes down to how you interpret the distribution.